# Updating taskpaper major mode to add date to @done tasks

Tags: major-mode

I am trying to update the fairly old taskpaper major mode for Emacs found [here](https://github.com/jedthehumanoid/taskpaper.el) to simply include the current date, whenever I mark a task as done. The line should then read:

`- Task @done(2015-07-13)` instead of just `- Task @done`.

Comment: I have just been pasting snippets I found in different major modes into the taskpaper.el file, but since I have very little experience programming nothing really worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing line 124 from `(insert " @done")` to this instead?:

[The example assumes that the original poster has a current version of Emacs that already has `(require 'org)` somewhere built-in.  If not, then add that statement to the `.emacs` file.  The example is a modified excerpt from the built-in function `org-insert-time-stamp`.]

```el
(let* ((inactive t)
       (with-hm t)
       (fmt (funcall (if with-hm 'cdr 'car) org-time-stamp-formats)))
  (when inactive (setq fmt (concat "[" (substring fmt 1 -1) "]")))
  (insert " @done" (format-time-string fmt (current-time))))
```

If the original poster prefers that the time-stamp be active, then change `(inactive t)` to `(inactive nil)`.

If the original poster does not want hours/minutes, then change `(with-hm t)` to `(with-hm nil)`.

Comment: How about simply `(insert " @done (%s)" (format-time-string taskpaper-timestamp-format (current-time)))` with a suitable definition of `taskpaper-timestamp-format`? I don't know what the rest of the code is for, but it sounds more complicated than what the OP asked for. And depending on org for inserting timestamps sounds like overkill, the relevant features are built-in emacs...

Comment: @T. Verron -- please post an alternative answer -- I am comfortable with mine just the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Sadly now the plugin doesn't load at all, and I get the following error when my Spacemacs loads: `load-with-code-conversion: End of file during parsing: /home/ma/.emacs.d/taskpaper.el
ad-handle-definition: 'tramp-read-passwd' got redefined`

Comment: Sorry, never mind! The mistake was elsewhere. It's working great now!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  The parsing error message usually means you forgot a parentheses or a double-quote somewhere.  Using `M-x check-parens` is very useful to help pinpoint the location.